# PHP considers two identical characters as different even with the same encoding

Tags: php, encoding

I have a PHP function that compares text strings to prevent the user from entering URLs. But there is a user who manages to enter URLs by entering characters with another encoding.

For example, these two "o" PHP consider them different even using **iconv** or **mb_convert_encoding** to match the encoding.

```
$a = "o";
$b = "о";  // U+043E CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER O

if($a == $b){
    echo "equal";
}else{
    echo "different: ".mb_detect_encoding($a)." - ".mb_detect_encoding($b);
}
```

Is there any function that escapes me so that both "o" PHP considers them the same?

Comment: PHP strings are just sequences of bytes. The regular PHP functions for strings (including the operators `==`, `===`, `!=` etc.) do not work with characters (possibly multi-byte characters) but with bytes. The two strings from your example are not equal anyway, even if you convert them to use the same encoding. You can, however, use `iconv()` to convert them to a format that makes them "equivalent".

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Transliterate any convertible utf8 char into ascii equivalent](//stackoverflow.com/q/13614622)